# Classify all groups of order 231 = 3.7.11

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am trying to work out this exercise, in which I have to prove there are only 2 groups of order 231 (up to isomorphism), one of those is of course $C_{231}$, and the other one will be a non-abelian group.

I already showed in a previous exercise that in the case $|G|=3\cdot 7\cdot 11$ we have that $G = H\rtimes C_3$, in which $H$ is a group of order 77. As a consequence of Sylow's theorems we have that $H = C_{77}$, thus we need to determine the possible semi-direct products $C_{77}\rtimes C_3$, this means we need to analyze the possible homomorphisms

$$\sigma:C_3 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(C_{77})$$

but we have $\text{Aut}(C_{77})\cong (C_{77})^* \cong C_{59}$, so in the end we need to see what are the homomorphisms

$$ \rho:C_3\rightarrow C_{59} $$

But the only possibility is the trivial homomorphism, which results in the direct product $C_{77}\times C_3 \cong C_{231}$.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because according to the book there are two possibilities, and I showed that there is only one, so there has to be something wrong in my solution, can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is writing $(C_{77})^* \cong C_{59}$. Notice $\phi(77) = \phi(7) \times \phi(11) = 6 \times 10 = 60$, not $59$.

Instead, we have that $(C_{77})^* \cong (C_7)^* \times (C_{11})^* \cong C_6 \times C_{10}$.

Comment: Thanks, I have just one more question, how can we know that $(C_{77})^*$ is cyclic? With my mistake it was trivial when the order was 59, but with order 60 there are other possibilities.

Comment: My mistake! We actually don't know it's cyclic. I'll edit

Comment: Ok, thanks, but is that last part true for any pair of distinct primes? If p,q are distinct primes then $(C_{pq})^* \cong (C_p)^*\times(C_q)^*$?

Comment: Yes, by the chinese remainder theorem $(C_{pq})^* \cong (C_p)^* \times (C_q)^* \cong C_{p-1} \times C_{q-1}$.

Comment: I see that the chinese remainder theorem gives $C_{pq} = C_p\times C_q$, but is it true in general that $(C_n\times C_m)^* \cong (C_n)^*\times (C_m)^*$, for any two primes $m,n$?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#General_composite_numbers)

Comment: I'm a tad confused. $G=H\rtimes C_3,$ where the order of $H$ is 77. Ok, but according to D & F, if $C_3\trianglelefteq G$, then the automorphism is the trivial one, which means $G$ is the abelian case. And $n_3=1$, so $C_3$ is a normal subgroup. This should imply there is only one group of order 231. Where am I going wrong? (If $K=C_7$ or $C_{11}$, then we only have the trivial automorphism into $\text{Aut}(H)$, so need not consider these cases.)

Comment: Figured my issue out. n_3 can be 7, as we cannot count elements of order, say 21, in a nonabelian group. Carry on